# mySQL query question

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, lookup-tables

I have and **ORDERS** table from a customer shopping cart.  It's the typical customer name, address, etc..list of fields.  The twist is that the cart will populate the shipping information into the appropriate fields (shipName, shipAddress, ShipState, etc) when the customer enters shipping information that is different then the billing information.  However, when the customer ships to themselves, the cart does not move the shipping information to the proper fields for shipping (i.e., shipName, shipAddress, shipState). It keeps this information in the ordName, ordAddress, ordCity, etc fields and then keeps the shipping related fields empty.

Therefore, these shipping fields are then empty for orders that customers ship to themselves.  I used IF commands to move the ordName, ordAddr, etc to alias names when no shipping information is provided so that the shipping information for all order types (whether the customer ships to themselves or to another address) is handled.  That part is working fine in my query below.

One issue remains.  My shipping program can't use long State name (e.g, Michigan, New York, etc).  It needs the state to be the two character abbreviation (e.g, MI, NY).  I have a look up table called **STATES* that has a mapping between long state name and the two character abbreviation.  I am trying to use the ShipState alias to look up the correct two character name for a given state.  I tried to do this as a JOIN but keep getting errors.  I removed the join I was using and am only showing the code that works correct right now but doesn't do the mapping for state abbreviation.  Can someone please help?

```
SELECT   
  orders.ordDate AS `Date`,  
  orders.ordID AS Order_ID,  
  orders.ordEmail AS Email,  
  IF(ordShipName = '          ', ordName, ordShipName) AS Name,  
  IF(ordShipAddress = '          ', ordAddress, ordShipAddress) AS Address_1,  
  IF(ordShipAddress2 = '          ', ordAddress2, ordShipAddress2) AS Address_2,  
  IF(ordShipCity = '          ', ordCity, ordShipCity) AS City,  
  IF(ordShipState = '          ', ordState, ordShipState) AS ShipState,  
  IF(ordShipZip = '          ', ordZip, ordShipZip) AS Postal,  
  IF(ordShipCountry = '          ', ordCountry, ordShipCountry) AS Country,  
  IF(ordShipPhone = '          ', ordPhone, ordShipPhone) AS Phone,  

FROM  
  orders   

WHERE  
  orders.ordID > 21700  
  HAVING  
  Country = 'United States of America'
```

Comment: Also, just a suggestion.  Could you change it so that the ordShipName, ordShipAddress columns are set to NULL when there is no data, and use the MySQL function ifnull()?  Seems like it would be a lot cleaner.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Good suggestion, however, the cart is a purchased product and I am reluctant to change any of the cart's data structures as any time I do an update to the cart, I will have to make that change also.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the column alias ShipState for the join to your lookup table. Instead, repeat your IF construct again:

```
SELECT   
  orders.ordDate AS `Date`,  
  orders.ordID AS Order_ID,  
  orders.ordEmail AS Email,  
  IF(ordShipName = '          ', ordName, ordShipName) AS Name,  
  IF(ordShipAddress = '          ', ordAddress, ordShipAddress) AS Address_1,  
  IF(ordShipAddress2 = '          ', ordAddress2, ordShipAddress2) AS Address_2,  
  IF(ordShipCity = '          ', ordCity, ordShipCity) AS City,  
  IF(ordShipState = '          ', ordState, ordShipState) AS ShipState,  
  IF(ordShipZip = '          ', ordZip, ordShipZip) AS Postal,  
  IF(ordShipCountry = '          ', ordCountry, ordShipCountry) AS Country,  
  IF(ordShipPhone = '          ', ordPhone, ordShipPhone) AS Phone,  
  STATE.StateAbbreviation
FROM  
  orders   
    INNER JOIN STATES
    ON IF(orders.ordShipState = '          ', orders.ordState, orders.ordShipState) = STATES.State

WHERE  
  orders.ordID > 21700  
  HAVING  
  Country = 'United States of America'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in where you try to join the two tables. You might just have a syntax error that someone could help you with. If you have a table called STATES with columns state and state_abrev, try this:

select ..., .., ..., STATES.state_abrev, ..., ..., from orders, STATES where STATES.state = orders.ordShipState AND ... ... HAVING ...

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly.  My ShipsState alias contains the long state name (New York, Michigan, etc) for every order.  I need to change the values represented in the ShipState alias to the state abbreviation using the STATES look up table.

Comment: Right, you would SELECT STATES.state_abrev (to get the abbreviation) FROM orders, STATES (both tables) WHERE orders.ordShipDate = STATES.state (AND order.ordID = userid*or w.e*)
Does that make sense? "WHERE orders.ordShipDate = STATES.state" would be like your join

Answer (score 0):

Since the origin of the data is a small set of transaction it will be very fast, I would have it do a left join to two instances of the states table respectively on their field and have your SELECT  based on whichever was not empty... such as

```
select 
     ...(other fields),
     IF(orders.ordShipState = '          ', s1.StateName, s2.StateName ) as StateName
   from 
      Orders
         left outer join states s1
            on orders.ordstate = s1.state
         left outer join states s2
            on orders.ordShipState = s2.state
   where 
      orders.ordID > 21700
      (etc with rest of query)...
```

This way, the join will always be having a join based on BOTH POSSIBLE states... So, whichever one exists, based on your preference, get THAT state first, otherwise get the other.